# Eigenvalues of a matrix multiplied by its transpose

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices, transpose

I recall being told that the eigenvalues of the matrix formed by multiplying a matrix by its transpose are the squares of the eigenvalues of the original matrix. Is that true for any matrix? Surely not.

Comment: they are squares of the singular values not eigenvalues

Answer (score 7):

No they're definitely not. Here's an easy counterexample:

$$
A=\left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
This matrix has eigenvalues $1$ and $0$ but 
$$
A^T A = \left( \begin{matrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)
$$
which has eigenvalues $2$ and $0$.

It is true if $A$ is a normal matrix (i.e. $A^T A = AA^T$) though.

Comment: Thanks it was the normal constraint I’d missed!

Comment: I think you are talking about Hermitian matrix not the normal one, because in normal matrix AA^T is not necessarily A^2

Answer (score 3):

No. Take $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\3&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, for instance. Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are $4$ and $-1$. But the eigenvalues of $A^t.A$ don't even belong to $\mathbb Z$; they are $9\pm\sqrt{65}$.

Answer (score 1):

No in general as explained above. But yes, if A is a Hermitian matrix because in Hermitian matrix: A=A* => $AA^T=A^2$ if A is of real values. And if λ is an eigenvalue of A, then $λ^2$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$. Also if λ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$ then $-sqrt(λ)$ and $+sqrt(λ)$ are eigenvalues of A.